# Valheim Dedicated Server Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose

I have read that a lot of poeple have issius by creating a Valheim Server with docker. So here is a default docker compose file which helps you to setup a valheim server in seconds.

The official documentation: [Valheim Dedicated Server](https://valheim.fandom.com/wiki/Valheim_Dedicated_Server)

The Valheim server is based on the docker image lloesche/valheim-server. For advanced config take a look at the dokumentation: [valheim-server-docker](https://github.com/lloesche/valheim-server-docker)

**Before start:**

*essential:*

Set "SERVER_NAME=", "WORLD_NAME=" and "SERVER_PASS=".

*optional:*

Change "container_name:"

If you want to run more than one container on the same maschine please make sure your maschin can handle this. Take a look at the documentation.

Change the volume names.

You also have to change the ports. Please only change the first port like this and make sure your firewall allow this ports:

```
#example:
        ports:
            - 2458:2456/udp
            - 2459:2457/udp
```

**Docker compose file for Valheim Dedicated Server:**

```
version: "3"
services:
    valheim-server:
        container_name: valheim_server
        image: lloesche/valheim-server
        cap_add:
            - sys_nice
        stop_grace_period: "120s"
        ports:
            - 2456:2456/udp
            - 2457:2457/udp
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - valheim-server:/config
            - valheim-server:/opt/valheim
        environment:
            - SERVER_NAME=
            - WORLD_NAME=
            - SERVER_PASS=

volumes:
  valheim-server:
```

I hope I could help some guys out there ;)

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question; what problem are you running into?  Remember that Stack Overflow questions must be programming-related, not just about deploying some prebuilt piece of software; also see the [help/on-topic].